# Best way adding custom property to radiobutton in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

What is the best way to add a custom property to a radiobutton in c#?

Background:

I'm developing a small **winform** tool and use 2 radiobutton groups to set some informations when hitting the execute button. Now I dont want to go for:

```
if(rb1.checked){...}
if(rb2.checked){...}
//and so on...
```

What I'm actually missing is a value property... in most languages like e.g. PHP checkboxes have at least 3 essential propertys...

- **Name/Class/ID** | to identify the checkbox
- **Text/Caption** | (or what ever you want to call it) to Show the user the caption
- **Value** | the value that gets submitted in case you need it.

I want to get the value returned. E.g. name of checkbox is `Foo` and the text or caption is `Bar` but the value that i want should be `hello world`.

The next thought was to create a radiobutton class that derives from radiobutton

```
class myRadioButton : RadioButton { ... }
```

But is this the best way... (seems to me like it is kind of overpowerd ?!?!) and is this the only way to achive this ?

I found some answere for asp adding some attributes to the xml parts... but I dont use asp and actually dont no if this is suiteable.

Comment: Wpf? winforms? asp.net? silverlight? some other UI framework I forgot to mention?

Comment: Sorry :D yes winform. added it to my question

Comment: What are you working with? Winforms? WPF? Please give us some further information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have identified, deriving from the existing RadioButton class is one possible solution.

But, another maybe simpler way is to use the "Tag" property which exists (I believe) on every Winforms control.

This is simply an object property for you to use as you wish.  So the easiest way is to add a string.

```
radioButton1.Tag = "Any string you like";
```

or you could add your own custom class

```
MyCustomClass myObj = new MyCustomClass { MyClassName = "Class Name", MyCaption = "Caption", MyValue = "Value to add" };
radioButton1.Tag = myObj;
```

And then you can use it when you need to.

```
MyCustomClass newObj = radioButton1.Tag as MyCustomClass;
if (newObj != null)
{
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is actually the missing property. Thank you very much! I hope this will help other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend the `RadioButton` class by a property I see no other way in `WinForms` then extending the class as you described. It is also recommended to do it that way.

This way you clearly separate the behavior of the control into a class and you won't pollute your business logic.

Comment: what about interfaces could this be a way as well ? or can't i use them like I'm thinking about it.. ?!?!

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to go with interfaces, I don't think that interfaces can help you here. Like I said in the answer: Deriving a custom control is they way you **should** change the behavior of a control!

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I just thought this could be a bit overpowerd for simply adding one property and there may be a other simple way.

Comment: What kind of property do you want to add anyway? That was not so clear in your question...

Comment: I added it allready. In my case i have 2 groups with each 3 radios. I want to get returned `left, `right` or `splitted` in each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ if you don't want to go for:

```
if(rb1.checked){...}
if(rb2.checked){...}
//and so on...
```

In LINQ you can write:

```
var checkedRadioButton = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                      .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Comment: but how to set the custom value in this case ? becaue I want to get that value returned. not the name or the text.

Comment: public class ValueCheckBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

Comment: What brings me back to the point of creating a class that derives from radiobutton. :) But thanks for the linq hint.

Comment: ill vote this up because its right but the "Tag" solution is kind of the missing value property i was searching for. still thank you :)